# MySql get different output from single sql command

Tags: mysql

In MySql database I have three tables as : `channels`, `channels_members` and `users`, `channels_members` linked to `channels` with `channel_id` and `channels` linked to `users` with `user_id`.

In channels table I'm storing created channels by users, each channel can be `is_auto` and `is_admin` or `is_user`, all of channels which they are flagged with 1 on `is_auto` that means: all users joined to that automatically, otherwise channel member is admin or user, now what do I want to do?

**1:** I want to get all channels which `is_auto` column equals with 1 without considering member role on `channels_members` table.

**2:** Get all channels with member role which that specific on `channels_members` table when `is_admin` is 1 and then

**3:** Get all channels with member role which that specific on `channels_members` table when `is_user` is 1 on this channel, for example: I have 4 channels

`channels` table:

```
id     channel_name   is_auto    user_id
1      debian           1          1
2      ubuntu           0          1
3      mint             0          1
4      fedora           0          1
```

`channels_members` table:

```
id     user_id        channel_id    is_admin   is_user 
1      1              1                0       1
2      1              2                1       0
3      1              3                0       1
4      1              4                0       1
```

output should be like this result

```
id     channel_name   is_auto    user_id   is_admin   is_user 
1      debian           1          1          0       1
2      ubuntu           0          1          1       0
3      mint             0          1          0       1
4      fedora           0          1          0       1
```

My command don't return correct result for this output

```
SELECT channels.channel_name FROM `channels` 
JOIN channels_members on channels.id = channels_members.channel_id 
JOIN users on users.id = channels.user_id where channels.is_auto =1 
OR channels_members.is_admin =1 
OR channels_members.is_user =1 and users.id = 1 
GROUP By channels.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `channels_members` twice with `channels` by adjusting the `on` clause part

```
select c.*,
coalesce(m1.is_admin,0) is_admin,
coalesce(m2.is_user,0) is_user
from `channels` c
left join channels_members m1 on c.id = m1.channel_id and m1.is_admin =1
left join channels_members m2 on c.id = m2.channel_id and m2.is_user =1
/* join with users table */
where c.user_id = 1 
order by c.id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0629a87/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try the next query, hoping it helps...

```
SELECT channels.channel_name,channels.is_auto, channels.user_id, channels_members.is_admin, channels_members.is_user FROM `channels` 
    INNER JOIN channels_members on channels.user_id = channels_members.user_id 
    GROUP By channels.id
```

Comment: i get this result:      `channel_name  is_auto  user_id  is_admin  is_user  
     debian        0        1        0        1
     ubuntu        0        1        0        1
`